# Get this form's attributes on a form submit even handler function

Tags: jquery, html

I want to be able to get one of the forms attributes (the `url` attribute), and save it as a variable on submit. I'm also having issues with getting the values from the comment box.

Here is my form in HTML:

```
<form class="comment_form" action="" url="comments/12/3/addcomment" method="post">
    <textarea name="commentField">Write your comment here...</textarea>
    <p align="center">
        <input type="submit" class="form-button" value="Submit Comment" />
        <input type="button" class="form-button" values="Cancel" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Here is my current javascript:

```
$('.comment_form').submit(function() { 
    alert("Working!"); // "Working!"
    var urlAttr = $(this).attr("url"); // Want to get the 'url' contained in the form tag. 
    alert(urlAttr); // undefined
    var dataString = 'comment=' + $("textarea#").value(); // want to get everything from the comment box
    alert(dataString) // No message at all here. 
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the `.comment_form` class applied to? because it doesn't seem to be on your form. Your form should be <form action="" url="comments/12/3/addcomment" method="post" class="comment_form"> otherwise that javascript will do nothing.

Comment: Ahh right sorry about that. I have updated the code above. It is actually inside the <form> tags.

Comment: Seems to work fine when I put it into jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/9QhyK/

Comment: Oh that's good. There must be an issue with some other code in my project then. But how come the dataString code isn't working? It's not alerting me with the text area? I'm not sure which selector to use.. i've tried #commentField, textarea#commentField and others...

Comment: `alert(dataString) // <-- missing a semicolon here maybe`

Comment: added an answer with a working jsfiddle, see if that does the trick. Otherwise you may have some other code interfering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/AWpbg

You were missing a semicolon at the end of `alert(dataString)`.

There is no `.value()` in jQuery, so I also changed `$('textarea').value()` to `$('textarea').html()`, but `$('textarea').val()` would also work.

Comment: It's still not working for me. When I test this out on Jsfiddle it is only giving out "Write your comment here..." however I want it to print whatever the user has written in the text area.

Comment: Also, if you copy and paste those forms it doesn't know which one to return and it all gets mixed up. Is there any way to get this to understand which text area to get?

Comment: Sorry, your correct. The js fiddle you posted works fine for me, however you used .value() in your code, which will not work. You have to use `.val()` or `.html()` to get the value of the textarea. http://jsfiddle.net/AWpbg/